# Entity Framework Code First Initial Create

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I first time trying to create web app (.net core 2.1) from scratch with Entity Framework. For some reason I can't get DB generated.

So I installed EF nuget. And did next things:

Added class that inheres from DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext:DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Server> Servers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Server>().HasData(
                new Server
                {
                    Name = "My Server",
                    InUse = false
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

And created Entity:

```
public class Server
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool InUse { get; set; }
    }
```

In startup.cs in ConfigureServices method I added:

```
var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationConnection");
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>
                    (options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

Connection string coming from appsettings and I debugged it so it does coming through, and it same string that I using in other projects with just different Database name value and it should be ok.

Also I run from console Add-Migration command so I got Migrations folder with InitialCreate migration and some snapshot file.

But when I run app I don't get any error but it never hit break point inside InitialCreate.cs migration and so never create DB.

Any ideas where and what should I call to trigger those?

Comment: Do you have a row for your migration in `__EFMigrationsHistory` table ?

Comment: No, the whole DB not created. So I run app -> no new DB in SQL server. So it not triggering DB creation.

Comment: Have you run `Update-Database` before running the app?

Comment: do you at least create a context in your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I been able to create DB by adding next code inside Startup.cs in Configure() method

```
      using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
            {
                var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                dbContext.Database.Migrate();

                if (!dbContext.Servers.Any())
                {
                    dbContext.Servers.Add(new Server
                    {
                        Name = "My Server",
                        InUse = false
                    });
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want entity framework automatically creates your database

   In Configuration file, add this line in constructor:
   `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;`

   Then add the code into DBContext:

   `Database.SetInitializer(new
   DropCreateDatabaseAlways<YourDbContext>());`

   Then when the application already ran:

   `Database.SetInitializer(new
   DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourDbContext>());`

   You can also have a look `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`
2. If you manually track version of database:

   Update `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;`

   From console, run command `Update-Database` to migrate your database
   manually

Comment: You can add `Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<YourDbContext>());` into your Startup code

Comment: For some reason I dont have any Configuration file...or do you mean Startup.cs Configure method?

Comment: yes, you can try calling Database.SetInitializer in Startup.cs or somewhere that runs when application start. This method will create database. The account in connection string should have permission to create database